# How to remove light edge from page of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface

I'm using a `UIPageViewController`.
I need to make the page opaque(frosted), without this light edge.

[image]

Comment: Please edit you question.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Have you try it on a real device?